# Hot deployment using jetty server

Tags: jetty, jetty-8, runjettyrun

I am using standalone jetty server in my application. I want to do a hot deployment for a jar. When I browsed through net I found the below settings in jetty.xml

```
<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.ContextDeployer">
      <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
      <Set name="configurationDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/contexts</Set>
      <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

`The ContextDeployer will scan the configurationDir directory at intervals of scanInterval seconds for xml descriptors that define contexts.`

In my case I have to do a hot deployment for a jar. Using the above configuration how can I specify to hot deploy for a jar file.  It is specified that it will look for changes in context files. So to redeploy should we need to make change to the context file ? Please help me in understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Your tagging indicates that you are using Jetty 8, but your example references org.mortbay classes which would be coming from Jetty 6 prior to our move to eclipse several years ago.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Hot_Deployment

The ContextDeployer was replaced with a ContextProvider and a more powerful deployment lifecycle in Jetty 7/8.  In Jetty 9 we merged the ContextProvider and WebappProvider into one (with the same deployment lifecycle setup)

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-deployment.html